# Does Cypher's ORDER BY uses the index?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an index on :Label(Uid) and :Label(Name)

However, when I profile (in the shell) the following two queries I get the same codepath for both. The issue is that I have 700,000 items of :Label, and it's starting to be painfully slow to order the items.

Query ordering by a property with index:

```
MATCH (item:Label) RETURN item.Name ORDER BY item.Name SKIP 1000 LIMIT 50
```

Query ordering by a property without index:

```
MATCH (item:Label) RETURN item.Name ORDER BY item.Created SKIP 1000 LIMIT 50
```

The profiler gets me (almost) the same thing for both, only the parameters are changed:

```
==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["item", "item.Name", "  UNNAMEDS885193287"], returnItemNames=["item.Name"], _rows=30, _db_hits=0)
==> Slice(skip="Literal(1000)", _rows=30, _db_hits=0)
==>   Top(orderBy=["SortItem(Cached(  UNNAMEDS885193287 of type Any),true)"], limit="Add(Literal(1000),Literal(50))", _rows=1030, _db_hits=0)
==>     Extract(symKeys=["item"], exprKeys=["item.Name", "  UNNAMEDS885193287"], _rows=768596, _db_hits=1537192)
==>       NodeByLabel(identifier="item", _db_hits=0, _rows=768596, label="Label", identifiers=["item"], producer="NodeByLabel")
```

Comment: what is your actual use-case?

Comment: why version are you using?

Comment: I need to sort some items that must appear on a table by a certain field. I do not grab the whole 700,000 items, but at least I'm grabbing around 200,000 in some cases (I have a previous "filtering" by graph traversal). I'm using 2.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of now, neo4j does not take advantage of an existing index to speed up the `ORDER BY` clause.

You should probably let the neo4j folks know you would like this to be supported :-).

[UPDATE]

There is, as of this update (Jan. 10, 2018), an [open feature request](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6584) for this capability. According to a recent comment, it is supposed to be a "high prioritized feature".

Answer (score 2):

As of Neo4j 3.4 using indexes for order by is supported. But you have to explain the data type of the property to the query engine. Adding a dummy where clause would be sufficient:

```
MATCH (item:Label)
WHERE item.Name > ""
RETURN item.Name 
ORDER BY item.Name 
SKIP 1000 
LIMIT 50
```

For details:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/cypher-index-values-order/#_index_backed_order_by