# Is Neo4j's new index mechanism taken into consideration when sorting with ORDER BY?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Node(property)
```

Will this index be taken into consideration when sorting with a cypher query (ORDER BY)? For example

```
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n ORDER BY n.property
```

If not, is there a way to achieve this (even considering the Lucene engine) so that a Cypher query could use it?

My business scenario is that there would be no filtering based on any relationship to the `Node` type nodes, but potentially there could be millions of these nodes.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835349/does-cyphers-order-by-uses-the-index/23835534#23835534. Also, here is a [forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/8iGd9B9VAKk) where Andres Taylor discusses the rather dense technical issues.

Comment: I wonder if this has changed with the new planner in 2.2?

Comment: No, ordering is not yet done using indexes.